# Can users in CommCare access users below them in the location hierarchy?

Tags: commcare

If I am a user at a location that can "View Child Data", I know I can see all locations and cases below me.  Do I also have access to the users assigned to those locations below me?

I want to be able to access their names, user_ids, and phone_numbers

Answer (score 2):

You will not have access to those users. Currently commcarehq does not have a way to send down user information about other users to a phone.